# CSV opens in browser and does not download in Safari

Tags: macos, csv, safari

I am trying to download a csv file from a website. It opens in the browser(Safari). 
I would like to download and save it.

Please can someone let me know how I can achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click the link to the csv file and select something along the lines of 'save target as'

this will prevent opening the file and allow you to save it wherever you wish :)

Comment: I don't think this provides the best user experience since it's not very intuitive for the user to know that a right click must be used.

Comment: This is just a feature of safari. It assumes that you would not need another program to handle csv (text) files and tries to provide the smoothest user experience by opening the file itself. I'd complain to Apple if you feel the user experience is not to your liking.